# Lost private keys. Help to recover

Tags: blockchain

I have blockchain wallet but have lost the private keys of it, is tr any way to restore my private keys. Plz help

Answer (score 3):

No, by design, there is no way for you or anyone to access your bitcoins without the private keys.

Unless you can find the keys somehow, you are out of luck. Sorry.