# how can i access my private key on the BIP39, if i only got my public address?

Tags: private-key-import, lost-wallet

actually, i can not access my private key of my wallet after a fire incident in my house. After which i realized i cant access my private key, i have gone to the bitcoin balance checker, checked on my last transaction info, then copy the hash addresses, and try hashing on BIP39 site. i paste the hash addresses i got from the bitcoin balance checker site into the BIP39 Seed to hash out either a corresponding root key, or identifying the address from the Derived Addresses details i got on the last transaction with my wallet address, but no avail, i am so confused and frustrated, someone should please help me i have lost access to my entire fund.

Comment: Sounds like you are pasting a bitcoin address into a BIP39 calculator, that won't work. Do you remember how you created this wallet originally? You should have been given a group of seed words when you created the wallet, do you have that?

Comment: i created the account since, but didnt save it anywhere apart of my laptop, and after the fire accident, i can access the group of seed. God!! please someone should help me or i am finished

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recover the private key for my bitcoin address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52568/how-can-i-recover-the-private-key-for-my-bitcoin-address) or [Lost private keys, Help to recover](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/30185/13866). or [How to recover my money](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/90069/13866)

Comment: If you don't have any private information, you can't access the funds for the same reason everyone else can't access the funds. You have to know something nobody else knows. What tool did you use the create the wallet and private key in the first place? What information did it give you? What do you still have?

Comment: sorry to everyone out here willing to help me on this, i am acting against doctors prescription just to meet up with all that could help me on this. back to all the questions asked,

Comment: regarding how i created this wallet it was on a Toshiba laptop. and for the private key address, i actually save the info on a notepad folder in the laptop

Comment: If the hard disk is destroyed, and you made no proper backups, your money is unrecoverable.